# How can I make an interactive world map in dash-leaflet?

Tags: plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

I'm trying to replicate [this example](https://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/#geojson) from the dash-leaflet documentation, but for world countries instead of US states. However, when I run the code from the documentation on my machine I don't see the blue state borders in the output visual.

I figured this was because I don't have the right geojson data locally, so I downloaded some country border GeoJSON data from [here](https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries) but it's unclear to me how to get the dl.GeoJSON function to make use of that data. How can I get country borders to show up on the world map in the same way the states do in the linked example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `url` property of the `GeoJSON` component to point to the data that you want to visualize. For all countries as shown in your link, the code would be along the lines of

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash

# An url pointing to the data that you want to show.
url = "https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/countries/archive/23f420f929e0e09c39d916b8aaa166fb/countries.geojson"
# Create example app.
app = Dash()
app.layout = dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), dl.GeoJSON(url=url)],
                    style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[image]